# How to find an exe and run it on visual basic

Tags: visual-studio

I've been making a project in visual basic that runs games, but i need help. Is there a way that when i click a button it will find a certain exe then if it finds that exe it will run it.

Comment: Yes, that is easy. But you will need to tell us how you intend to find that .exe, and what version of visual basic you're using...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sometimes you need to do exactly that. In my case, I am working on developing RTMaps packages using msvc and for that I need to run RTMaps(exe) for debugging and other stuff.

The way I am doing this is adding the .exe path as following

```
Project->Propreties->Debugging->Command =>(path_to_exe)
```

This way, clicking on debug will launch the ".exe" program you attached.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks but thats not really what i asked... I asked if you could make it find the exe without a path.